# Insert Button in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I am using swing in Java and I need to create a JButton and put it in a JPanel.

I reed tutorials and I did this:

```
public void crearNuevaMiga(String nombre)
{
    JButton nuevo = new JButton(nombre);
    this.MigasDePan.add(nuevo);
    nuevo.setVisible(true);
    nuevo.setLocation(new Point(migaX, migaY));
    System.out.println(nuevo.getLocation().x + " "+ nuevo.getLocation().y);
    migaX = migaX-avanceMigas;
}
```

I do that and when I call the function, I cant see the button. I put a button with the designer of NetBeans and get X and Y Location. Then, in the variables migaX and migaY I put that X and Y Location, so the button need to be in the same position, but it is not there.

Anyone knows why? Maybe putting the location in that way is not correct?

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: MigasDePan is my JPanel

Comment: Try calling `this.MigasDePan.repaint();` after adding the button, and setting its locations.

Comment: No, the repaint doesnt work :/

Comment: Your mistake was using the NetBeans designer.  Until you've done a couple of hundred GUIs by hand, and understand [Swing architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), you're going to run into problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default components have a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

When you dynamically add a button to a visible GUI you need to invoke the layout manager so the components size/location can be determined by the layout manager.

The basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example of putting a JButton in a JPanel, and putting the JPanel in a JFrame.  I created this code without using any GUI builder.

1. I called the SwingUtilities invokeLater method in the main method to put the creation and use of the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).  Oracle and I insist that you start every Swing application on the Event Dispatch thread.
2. I used a JFrame.  You must call the JFrame methods in the order they are called in the run method.
3. I used a JPanel.  I put the JButton in the middle of the JPanel, since it's the only component on the JPanel.
4. I used a [Swing layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), the Border Layout.  Different Swing layouts are used to create different Swing component layouts.

Here's the short, self-contained, **runnable** code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyButton implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MyButton());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Button");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMainPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton myButton = new JButton("My Button");
        panel.add(myButton);

        return panel;
    }

}
```